# How come a question reaches ~400 views in 40 minutes?

Tags: discussion

I wonder how come that [Detecting a WordPress URL without doing a full HTTP GET?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54437/detecting-a-wordpress-url-without-doing-a-full-http-get) question reached ~400 views in ~40 mins?
Approximate number of views of sibling question is ~15 views for longer time frame. How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jeff Atwood tweeted it](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/210633668241268736). I guess this will be his next [Publicist badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist). :)

Comment: ah I see, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible [when you have seventy thousands followers on twitter](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/210633668241268736).